# UrlFetchApp.fetch windows-1251

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to get the title page of the head unit

I expect to get
Страховые компании Уфы. Адреса отделений в Уфе

And get
��������� �������� ���. ������ ��������� � ���

sample script:

```
function doGet() {
  var options1 = {
    contentType: "text/html; charset=windows-1251",
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var url_catalog = 'http://ufa.insure-company.ru/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_catalog, options1);
  var txt = response.getContentText();
  doc = Xml.parse(txt, true);
  var tbody = doc.html.head;
  var title = tbody.getElements("title");
  var t = title[0].getText();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function doGet() {
  var options1 = {
    contentType: "text/html ",
    muteHttpExceptions: true
 };
  var url_catalog = 'http://ufa.insure-company.ru/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_catalog, options1).getContentText("windows-1251");      
  doc = Xml.parse(response, true);
  var tbody = doc.html.head;
  var title = tbody.getElements("title");
  var t = title[0].getText();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(t);
}
```

It actually was answered in the old product forum see the answer [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/PPxemz_MHaM/discussion)

You get the context in the UrlFetchApp class  with getContentText().

[Working example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/dev-test/dev-test-charsets)